# Trying to get cell data + select option from cell with TABULATOR

Tags: javascript, ajax, tabulator

I'm using Tabulator, an amazing tool by the way, but I'm having a trouble. I want to put a HTML Select in all Rows, with option for each record. When I change the select option, I call a function, and I'm receiving the cell data (with `cell.getData()`). But how do I get the select option value too?

[This is what I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4kOy.png)

What I have:

```
var selectHTML = function() {
    return '<select class="custom-select" id="select1" name="select1"><option value="0">Select</option><option value="1">Option 1</option><option value="2">Option 2</option></select>';};

var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
langs: {
    "es-es": {
        "pagination": {
            "first":"Primer página",
            "first_title":"Primer página",
            "last":"Última página",
            "last_title":"Última página",
            "prev":"Anterior",
            "prev_title":"Anterior",
            "next":"Siguiente",
            "next_title":"Siguiente",
            "page_size":"Resultados a mostrar"
        },
        "ajax":{
            "loading":"Cargando",
            "error":"Error"
        },
    },
},
height:"500",
layout:"fitColumns",
placeholder:"Sin datos",
responsiveLayout:true,
pagination:"local",
paginationSize:10,
paginationSizeSelector:[3, 6, 8, 10, 50],
movableColumns:true,
columns:[
    {title:"Zipcode", field:"zipcode", sorter:"number"},
    {title:"Productor", field:"nombre", sorter:"string"},
    {title:"Action", formatter:selectHTML, cellClick:function(e, cell){
        var element = cell.getElement().children.select1.value;
        test(element, cell.getData());
    }},
    {title:"", formatter:editIcon, align:"center", cellClick:function(e, cell) {
        var data = cell.getData();
        modificar_nombre(data);
    }},
],
locale:"es-es"
```

});

```
function test(selectedOption, data) {
    if(selectedOption != 0) {
        alert("Chosed option: " + selectedOption);
    }
}
```

Looking forward for any response. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Code submited...

Comment: See this: https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/129

Comment: Thanks @No Grabbing!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I fixed my problem like this:

```
var element= cell.getElement().children.select1.value;
test(element, cell.getData());
```

*test is the name of the function

Buuuut...the problem is that test() is executed anytime I'm clicking the cell:

```
{title:"Action", formatter:selectHTML, cellClick:function(e, cell) {
        var element = cell.getElement().children.select1.value;
        test(element, cell.getData());
}},
```

and I just wanna execute it if the select option change...

So I'll wait for any response. Cheers!